# Upon creation of 3 - 5 nodes, segmentation fault is encountered. Why?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am currently trying to create a phonebook with a linked list. I am focusing first on the insertion function but the problem is that once I create 3 - 5 nodes, onlineGDB shows the error "malloc : corrupted top size", and VS Code shows that I got a segmentation error.

I assume this is an error with the way I am allocating memory. This is the first time that I am working on a structure that contains strings as data instead of integer so I might have missed a thing or two.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node{
    char name[30];
    char number[15];
    struct node *next;
};

void showMenu();
void insertData(struct node **head, char person[], char phone[]);
void showData(struct node *head);

int main(){

    struct node *head = NULL;
    char name[30], number[15];
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Name : ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", name);
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", number);
        insertData(&head, name, number);
        showData(head);
    }
    return 0;
}

void insertData(struct node **head, char person[], char phone[]){

    struct node *new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    strcpy(new_node->name, person);
    strcpy(new_node->number, phone);
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}

void showData(struct node *head){

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t%s\n", head->name, head-> number);
        head = head->next;
    }    
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` You want to store a `struct node` in that memory location, not a pointer to `struct node`. A pointer is only 4 or 8 bytes, way too small for your struct  => `malloc(sizeof(struct node));` or `malloc(sizeof(*new_node));`

Comment: Side note: the cast isn't needed with `malloc`:  `(struct node*)malloc(...` -> `malloc(...`

Comment: Note that these scanf calls are [vulnerable to buffer overruns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/10077).

Comment: @Gerhardh this worked. Thank you so much! So everytime I use malloc for linked lists, I always use the size of the structure itself? Not a pointer to the structure?

Comment: `" %[^\n]s"` is not what you want.  That matches (and consumes) all input up to the first newline.  The next character is a newline, so the `s` is guaranteed not to match.  The `[^\n]` is *not* some sort of modifier for a `%s` conversion specifier.  Your format string is trying to match a literal `s`.  Use `" %29[^\n]"` and `" %14[^\n]"`

Comment: _"So everytime I use malloc for linked lists, I always use the size of the structure itself? Not a pointer to the structure?"_: yes, obviously. Every time you allocate memory for a structure you need to allocate enough memory so you can store that structure.

Comment: @Jabberwocky one question, when do I need to cast malloc()? Been doing it out of habit for the past semester.

Comment: @blurridge you never need to cast the return value of `malloc`. `malloc` returns a `void*` and `void*` are safely promoted to any pointer type.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I used that format to make sure that the buffer does not carry over to the next string. Will your formatting also make it work?

Comment: If you use the pattern `x = malloc( n * sizeof *x )` you don't need to think about it.  In your case, that would be `struct node *new_node = malloc(1 * sizeof *new_node);` (the `1*` here is unnecessary, but given to be explicit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` instead of `malloc(sizeof(struct node*))` in your function `insertData()`. You want to allocate the size of the node and not the pointer to node.